# Strange issue with Product custome attribute

Tags: magento-1.8, custom-options, product-attribute, save, edit

From last 5 days, I am facing problem with related to product custom attribute.
I have created some extra attribute for product and "Donation"(Mandatory field) attribute is one of them. It was working fine but from last 5 days I am noticed that Product Id from 1 to 800 were not at all saving this attribute.
New product which are created now are working fine they have attribute donation and value as well.

Only for old product, When I edit them I am not seeing the donation value in text box. I need to enter it again to save it but even though the value is not saving.

Can Any one suggest me what can I do? and Why this is happening.

**Note: Some days back we have edited Donation attribute and changed its validation class and made it to accept values from 10 to 100 only.**

***In magento if we edit the product custom attribute properties, Is there any chance of loosing data/value of previous created products?***

Comment: Have you reindexed the Product Attribute index?

Comment: @TylerV. Yes, I did it